# How can I change hour to minutes in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a list of hours, showing like this
*2.52 (meaning 2hours 52 minutes)
3
3.63

3.33

2.94

2.52*
How can I convert this to # of minutes?

Comment: Does 2.94 mean 2 hours and 94 minutes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a list of hours, showing like this 2.52 (meaning 2hours 52
> minutes)

If the scale part shows the minutes, we should directly add it directly to the total minutes:

```
select col, TRUNC(col) * 60 + (col % 1 * 100) minutes
from values (3.63),(2.94) tmp(col);
```

If they are the percentage of the hour (which makes more sense), then this can give you the result:

```
select col, TRUNC(col) * 60 + round(col % 1 * 60) minutes
from values (3.63),(2.94) tmp(col);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the value of "2.94" - why is it 2 hours and 94 minutes and not 3.34, which would be the same amount of overall minutes?

Based on above assumption, you can use POSITION and SUBSTRING to split the string into the hour- and minute-part and then do the maths. First part of below query is extracting the left side of the dot and is multiplying it with 60, second part is just putting the minutes on top.

```
WITH hours AS (SELECT 3.63 as hour_value UNION SELECT 3.33 UNION SELECT 2.94)
select substr(hour_value, 0, position('.' in hour_value))*60 + substr(hour_value,position('.' in hour_value)+1) from hours;
```

In case the right side of the dot is NOT minutes, but the percentage of the whole hour, then you could just go with

```
select hour_value*60 from hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [TIME_FROM_PARTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/time_from_parts.html):

```
SELECT col, TIME_FROM_PARTS(FLOOR(col), col % 1 * 60, 0)
FROM tab;
```

Sample:

```
3.33
FLOOR(3.33) -> 3h
3.33 % 1 * 60 -> 0.33 * 60 -> 20 min
```